# MATLAB - Cell array to a cell

Tags: matlab, assign, cell-array

I want to create a {1,2} cell array, that will contain single cell value in {1,1} and several cells in {1,2}{:,1} row:

```
TEXT = {'-1';'432';'a';'c';'v';'-1';'-1';'14';'b';'n';'-1';'-1';'44';'m';'t';'r';'-1';'-1';'55';'o';'i';'u';'-1'};

Sections{1,1} = TEXT{5}; 
Sections{1,2}{:,1} = TEXT{3:10,1};
```

,but I get an ERROR:

```
The left hand side is initialized and has an empty range of indices.
However, the right hand side returned one or more results.
Error in fff (line 4)
Sections{1,2}{:,1} = TEXT{3:10,1}; % Text in the section
```

Ideas?

Comment: maybe try `clear` and re-run your code? Since i got no error with your example

Comment: please add the desired content of  `Sections` for your example input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `()` instead of `{}` for the sections in (n,2):

```
TEXT = {'-1';'432';'a';'c';'v';'-1';'-1';'14';'b';'n';'-1';'-1';'44';'m';'t';'r';'-1';'-1';'55';'o';'i';'u';'-1'};

Sections{1,1} = TEXT{5}; 
Sections{1,2} = TEXT(3:10,1);
```

Comment: LOL thanks, you are so strict in matters of principle

Comment: Hah, not really. I corrected it just before you post the answer, as it seemed that people were confused with all the "unrelevant" code. Thanks!